# How to check if the variable is set in the parent scope, (as opposed to being inherited from grandparents) in CMake?

Tags: cmake, scope

How to check if the variable is set in the parent scope, (as opposed to being inherited from grandparents) in CMake?

In the ideal world, I would fancy having some sort of `DEFINED_IN_PARENT_SCOPE` predicate for the `if` construct, so in the following code

```
function(child)
   if(DEFINED MYVAR) #First check if the variable is defined in any of the parents
      if(DEFINED_IN_PARENT_SCOPE MYVAR)
         message("Parent has defined MYVAR")
      else()
         message("Parent has inherited MYVAR from other function up in the call stack")
      endif()
   else()
      message("No MYVAR defined")
   endif()
endfunction()

function(parent1)
   set(MYVAR 1)
   child()
endfunction()

function(parent2)
   child()
endfunction()

function(grandparent1A)
   set(MYVAR 1)
   parent1()
endfunction()

function(grandparent1B)
   parent1()
endfunction()

function(grandparent2A)
   set(MYVAR 1)
   parent2()
endfunction()

function(grandparent2B)
   parent2()
endfunction()

grandparent1A()
grandparent1B()
grandparent2A()
grandparent2B()
```

would yield

```
Parent has defined MYVAR
Parent has defined MYVAR
Parent has inherited MYVAR from other function up in the call stack
No MYVAR defined
```

I can walk around this problem if I knew how to solve [How to write a variable to the parents' parent scope in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56295714/1261153) .

Comment: The needs for checking which function creates a variable look very strange for me. What ultimate goal do you want to achieve? Probably, there are others, more CMake-friendly ways for achieve it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I am developing https://beetroot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @Tsyvarev it will need that functionality to infer whether the user had modified a variable inside his function before calling the library again.

Comment: You may **store copy of the variable** into another place before calling a user function. When your library function is called again, compare values of the variable's and its copy. Depending on the context/scope, where your variable is used, its copy can be stored as CACHE variable, GLOBAL property, DIRECTORY property and so on. It would be easy to help if you provide "toy" example of what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Of course and this is exactly what I've done. But there is a problem when user's function (that sits between the two functions of my library in the call stack) sets the variable with a value that just happens to be exactly the same, as the inherited (default) one. It is a corner case, I know, but I in the ideal world I would like to handle it differently.

Comment: Setting the value to the default should be effectively the same as not set it at all. If in your case the "default" is not the same as any value set by a user, assign some **special** value as default one, which has no sense to be set by a user. E.g. CMake itself uses `-NOTFOUND` suffix for the variable's value for differentiate it from any legal filepath. In any case, "toy example" of your needs would be helpful.

Comment: I am creating a set of CMake macros that tries to push CMake more into a realm of functional languages. The user defines his targets by formally defining its parameters (with types, validation, and the default value) and putting the CMake code into the function. This function is called with the variables initialized according to the specs. When the user calls a library function "`add_dependency`" to add a dependency to his target, some of the parameters might be inherited. Now I want to know, whether the parameter was manually modified by the user in his function's body, or was it left alone.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Inferring the modification of the variable by comparing its value with its default value results in a situation where changing the default value of the variable that user always modifies before use anyway would unexpectedly change the behaviour. Knowing how scoping works I believe that the information of whether the function was re-assigned in a parent scope is available, so in theory I suppose there might be a way to get that information.  That is why I posted the question here.

Comment: "I believe that the information of whether the function was re-assigned in a parent scope is available, so in theory I suppose there might be a way to get that information." - I know no such way. You may try to perform following trick with CACHE and normal variables: Before call a user code use `set(var_A <default-value> CACHE INTERNAL "")` and `unset(var_A)`. After a user code call `unset(var_A CACHE)`. After that, if `${var_A}` is not empty, then (I suppose) it is set by a user. Quite a dirty way, but probably it works.