# How to write a variable to the parents' parent scope in CMake?

Tags: cmake, scope

I know that when I am in a function, I can set the variable in the calling scope by using:

```
set(MYVAR 1 PARENT_SCOPE)
```

What I want is to be able to set a variable in the grandparent scope (if it exists).

I know that if I redefine my function as a macro, then `set(MYVAR 1 PARENT_SCOPE)` effectively does what I need. But unfortunately, I cannot do that for unrelated reasons.

A solution would work for me as a walkaround for the problem in [How to check if the variable is set in the parent scope, (as opposed to being inherited from grandparents) in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56295623/1261153) .